# Can I invest in the London stock market when resident on a visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, stock-exchanges

Can holders of a "Tier 2 Skill Transfer UK Visa" invest in the London stock market?

If so, what is the procedure?

Comment: Is there any reason you'd think you can't? What's the difference from any other UK resident in that respect?

Comment: It is the same as any UK resident, visa doesn't come unless you want to borrow something. Contact an online broker of your choice and open an account.

Answer (score 1):

There are no legal restrictions on doing this. If you're living in the UK, just open an account like any other resident of the UK would.